# Metapopulation structure - book recommendations

Tags: evolution, ecology, population-dynamics, book-recommendation, population-genetics

What book would you recommend me to study:

- the dynamics of metapopulations,
- the structure of metapopulations,
- the evolution in structured metapopulations?

I am not looking for an introduction but for a book that offers good and extensive mathematical formulations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the best source to start would be Ilkka Hanksi's work, you can find a full list here: http://www.helsinki.fi/science/metapop/People/IlkkaPub2.htm.  The seminal work would be "Ecology, Genetics and Evolution of Metapopulations"  It gives a strong mathematical treatment

Comment: I was indeed thinking about "Ecology, Genetics and Evolution of Metapopulations". Thank you!